SQLite cannot open the desired database file
SqfliteFfiException (SqfliteFfiException(sqlite_error: 14, , open_failed: SqliteException(14): while opening the database, unable to open database file, unable to open database file (code 14)}) DatabaseException(open_failed: SqliteException(14): while opening the database, unable to open database file, unable to open database file (code 14)))
How can I fix this exception?

Can you share the code you have in place that causes this exception?

Try to open the file using one of the common SQLite UI tools to check if the file can be opened (is not corrupt).
